# stop Repetition data when display data from api to gridview android

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridView` in the Android application I am developing, and I get data to this `GridView` from an API and store the API data into the local database and then display it in the `GridView`. My problem is when I display data for the first time its ok, but when I restart the app's  `GridView`, repetition of the data occurs.

```
 JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            hidePDialog();

            // Parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Movie movie = new Movie();
                    movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));


                    // adding movie to movies array
                    movieList.add(movie);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            // notifying list adapter about data changes
            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });
```

How can I stop this in my `GridView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Set data (eg: HashSet) structure for removing the duplicates.

Steps :

1. Inside the Movie class, override the equals and hashcode method and define your own definition.
   hashcode : you can return the sum of hashcode of title and thumbnail url
   equals : you can return based on comparing the title and thumbnail url.
2. Inside the onResponse method, create a Hashset and then add the movie objects to the hash set. Once you have added all items, copy the hashset values to the list and use it.You will get unique Grid items output.

   ```
   public class Movie{

   public String thumbnailUrl;
   public String title;

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return 31 * title.hashCode() + thumbnailUrl.hashCode();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if(o instanceof Movie){
           Movie other = (Movie) o;
           return other.title.equalsIgnoreCase(title) && other.thumbnailUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(thumbnailUrl);
       }
       return false;
   }
   }
   ```

In onResponse Method :

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        .....

        HashSet<Movie> set = new HashSet<Movie>();
        set.add(movie);

        .....

        movieList.addAll(set);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HashSet instaed of Arraylist ,set remove duplicacy